# Stripe payment Integration in android Error java.lang.RuntimeException: Required Parameter: 'card' is required to create a token

Tags: android

I have the following code where I want to implement Stripe payment in android application.please any tell how this problem i can solve if i giving card number dinamically in code like `this:card = new Card("4242424242421111", 12, 2019, "123");`  then after success token is creating but i can't give card number dynamically eachtime. so that i have added  `CardInputWidget` in my xml layout and writing this code:

```
CardInputWidget mCardInputWidget = (CardInputWidget) findViewById(R.id.card_input_widget);
card = mCardInputWidget.getCard();
```

then j`ava.lang.RuntimeException: Required Parameter:` 'card' is required to create a token how can i solve this issues i am trying to solve this since last one day but unable to solve

**my full code:**

```
  Card card;
    public static final String PUBLISHABLE_KEY = "pk_test_djaC9oh3D3xwh8FxOjh7pnew";
        private ProgressDialog progress;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maincard);
            btnsubmit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);

            CardInputWidget mCardInputWidget = (CardInputWidget) findViewById(R.id.card_input_widget);

          card = mCardInputWidget.getCard();

       //     card = new Card("4242424242424242", 12, 2018, "123");
            if (card == null) {
                //    mErrorDialogHandler.showError("Invalid Card Data");

                Stripe stripe = null;
                try {
                    stripe = new Stripe(MainActivity.this, PUBLISHABLE_KEY);
                } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                stripe.createToken(
                        card,
                        new TokenCallback() {
                            public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                                // Send token to your server
                                Log.d("token","token"+token);
                            }
                            public void onError(Exception error) {
                                // Show localized error message
                                Log.d("token","excep"+error.getMessage());

                            }
                        }
                );
            }`
```

**activity_maincard.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.mspl.stripepay.MainActivity"
        xmlns:wallet="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget
            android:id="@+id/card_input_widget"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my xml containing `CardInputWidget` please try to help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got my solution to get Card Information using `CardInputWidget` code.
Here is how I did it:

```
if(mCardInputWidget.getCard()!=null){
   String cvv= mCardInputWidget.getCard().getCVC();
   int exp= mCardInputWidget.getCard().getExpMonth();
   int exp_year= mCardInputWidget.getCard().getExpYear();
   String card_num= mCardInputWidget.getCard().getNumber();

   card = new Card(card_num, exp, exp_year, cvv);
}
```